CodeIgniter 4 - Validation in Session lost after page refresh
I'm trying to sending errors message after my form getting the validation. When I tried to dump the errors message before the page refresh, my validation show the errors message. But when the page is refresh and go to direction method, all the errors is disappear.
Here's my code :
public function assetsAdd() 
    {
        if(!$this->validate([
            'title' => 'required'
        ])) {
            $validation = $this->validation;
            dd($validation);
            return redirect()->to('/home/newAssets')->withInput()->with('validation', $validation);
        }
    }

When I dump the validation, here's the result :
enter image description here
But after I sending the validation to newAssets method, the list errors is disappear like this :
enter image description here
Please I need your help.
Something wrong with my code ?
